# django count queryset field in listview template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

**Question which i am stuck with.**

I want to count `venlist.Status` which is equal to Active and show it in some html tag

Please let me know if you need more details on my question as this is my first post and been searching for it in the library fromm almost 4 hours

> Models.py

```
VendorCH= [
    ('Active', 'Active'),
    ('BlackList', 'BlackList'),
]

class VendorModel(models.Model):
    Name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=40)
    President=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=40)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=VendorCH,default='Active')
```

> Forms.py

```
class VendorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = VendorModel
        exclude=['VendorStatus']
```

> views.py

```
class VendorCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView):
    template_name = "ePROC/Administration/Vendor_Create.html"
    model=VendorModel

    fields=['Name','President']
    success_message = "Record was created successfully"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ePROC:ePROCHOME')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.Status = 'Active'
        return super(VendorCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

> List_Template.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <th> Vendor Name</th>
    <th> President</th>
    <th> Status</th>                                        
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for venlist in object_list %}
   <tr> 
       <td>{{ venlist.VendorName }}</td>
       <td>{{ venlist.President}}</td>
       <td>{{ venlist.Status}}</td>                                     
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
<tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class VenderListView(ListView):
    queryset=VendorModel.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_active_records'] = self.queryset.filter(Status='Active').count()
        return context
```

> List_Template.html:

```
<div>Total Active Vendors: <span> {{ total_active_records }}</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, based on [Umar Asghar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47962374).

```
class IndexListView(ListView):
    template_name = "ePROC/Base/index.html"
    model = CreateReqModel
    context_object_name = 'reqlists'
    queryset=CreateReqModel.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['total_active_records'] = self.queryset.filter(Status='Initiate').count()
        context['range'] = range(context["paginator"].num_pages)
        return context
```